# WPF appication to create MsSql database

Tags: wpf, database, sql-server-2008

I want to know how to create a WPF application to, create a MsSql database, View existing databases & tables, create a backup of databases & restore the backup. Please help me if anyone knows this. I'm stucked with my project & this is so crucial for me.
Thank you

Comment: Does [SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593) not work for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking into Microsoft's [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for something like this. It provides all of the features you listed in a convenient .NET assembly.